# Convert a CSV file to html in required format

Tags: html, linux, bash

I have a csv file say file.csv which has content as below:

```
Android_1,10.24.420.105,Attached,0A251FDD4000D1/13,27071JEGR10369/12,4075252kB,2387900kB,100,76

And_perf,10.24.424.99,Attached,93BAY08V2A/10,FA7AK1A02097/10,G0011K05020607NC/9,2111612kB,2028448kB,596888kB,100,88,98
```

First column provides hostname, second column is ip address of host, third tells if any device is attached to host, after this few columns shows name of connected device/version, after this each column show as available memory for each connected device respectively and lastly few column as battery status respectively.

I want to send an email for above data so want to convert csv file to a html file by modifying above file.csv as below:

```
MACHINE_NAME  IP_ADD     DEVICE_CONN CONN_DEVICE_NAME/OS_VERSION  MEMORY_AVAILABLE BATTERY_LEVEL

Android_1   10.24.420.105   Attached    0A251FDD4000D1/13           4075252kB           100
                                        27071JEGR10369/12           2387900kB            76

And_perf    10.24.424.99    Attached    93BAY08V2A/10               2111612kB           100 
                                        FA7AK1A02097/10             2028448kB            88
                                        G0011K05020607NC/9          596888kB             98
```

I tried to convert the file.csv file as first in another csv file

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "MACHINE_NAME,IP_ADDRESS,DEVICE_CONNECTED,CONNECTED_DEVICE_NAME,DEVICE_OS_VERSION,MEMORY_AVAILABLE,BATTERY_LEVEL%"}; {print $0};' file.csv | \
tee file2.csv
```

and then tried to convert file2.csv to file.html as below:

```
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN { FS=",";
        print "<html><head><style>table {font: 2.1ex calibri}"
        print ".green {border: 1px solid green}"
        print ".red {border: 1px solid red}"
        print ".sample {border: 1px solid red; color:white}"
        print "td:first-child {width:150px}</style></head>"
        print "<body><br><br><table width=500 border=2 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2 border-collapse=collapse>"}
        NR == 1 { print "<tr bgcolor=\"#FAD7A0\">";
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) print "<td><b>" $i "</b></td>";
        print "</tr>"}
        NR > 1  { print "<tr>";
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
            print "<td" (i==7? " class=" ($i>50?"green":"red"):"") ">" $i "</td>";
        print "</tr>"}
        END { print "</table></body></html>"}' \
file2.csv > file.html
```

but it sends the email like below:

```
MACHINE_NAME  IP_ADD      DEVICE_CONN CONN_DEVICE_NAME/OS_VERSION  MEMORY_AVAILABLE BATTERY_LEVEL
Android_1,10.24.420.105,Attached,0A251FDD4000D1/13,27071JEGR10369/12,4075252kB,2387900kB,100,76
And_perf,10.24.424.99,Attached,93BAY08V2A/10,FA7AK1A02097/10,G0011K05020607NC/9,2111612kB,2028448kB,596888kB,100,88,98
```

Comment: Nothing here shows how you sent the email.  Clearly, you are creating an HTML document, but you would need to send a `multipart/alternative` mail with a `text/html` section to send the HTML.

Comment: My doubt is not how to send the email but how to format the CSV in the required html format.

Comment: If I open the `file.html` generated as shown above in a browser, I get a proper HTML table. If you don't get one in the _email_, apparently there's something wrong after the shown procedure. Strangely enough, you show commas in the E-mail's data lines, which are not present in my `file.html`.

Comment: If your "doubt is not how to send the email" then remove all references to sending email from your question and ONLY make it about how to create the HTML from the CSV, Add the actual HTML (not a spaces-separated, tabular rendition of it) you want the script to output from the input you provided so we can see what you want and copy/paste your input/output to test a potential solution with.

Comment: It is absolutely impossible for the script you posted to produce the output you say it does under "it sends the email like below" - that looks like your just emailing the input CSV file instead of the output HTML file. Please fix your question.

Comment: Do you see the point we're trying to make?  Your code to create the HTML is just fine. THEREFORE, the mistake you have made is in how you sent the email, which you have not shown us.